# how creating a simple function in javascript that works

Tags: javascript, html

my problem is that i cant make the function to show the result in the inner htnml when you **click** on the button ! **plz click to show what happens** ....
thanks .
this is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

the text: 
<input type="text" id="userp" /> 
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction () " value="click"> </button> 
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myfunction () {
var usert = document.getElementById("userp");
var resul = usert +3 ; 



document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resul;}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use `usert.value` to get an input's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the following line

```
var resul = usert +3 ;
```

because `usert` it's a `DOM` element and you need firstly to get the value using `value` *property*.
`document.getElementById` method *returns* an `Element` object describing the `DOM` element object matching the specified ID, or `null` if no matching element was found in the document.

```js
function myfunction () {
var usert = document.getElementById("userp");
var resul = usert.value +3 ;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = resul;}
```

```html
the text: 
<input type="text" id="userp" /> 
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction () " value="click"> </button> 
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var usert = document.getElementById("userp");
```

**instead of**

```
var usert = document.getElementById("userp").value
```

it should work now